# Spinner in custom ActionBar View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-actionbar

Please provide any example of custom ActionBar view with spinner.  I've searched the web and stackoverflow but didn't found anything. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have tried to make ActionBar with tabs and drop down list, but that didn't work because android doesn't allow to use them both. I don't know how to implement custom ActionBar view, and I didn't find any information about it in Android Dev. documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get better idea about Action bar Drop down : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown

It can help you!

Comment: In my application I've used ActionBar tabs, so I can't use Drop Down list at the same time:(

Comment: http://actionbarsherlock.com/index.html : use this action bar api it might help you.